# How to set default NON-transparent background in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.android

I just started developing with Xamarin Forms and facing a rather simple problem, but I could not find a solution:
I have some UI elements stacked over each other like the following:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label x:Name="LabelLeft" Grid.Column="0" Text="LEFT" />
    <Label x:Name="LabelRight" Grid.Column="2" Text="RIGHT" />

    <Grid x:Name="GridMain" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0"
          BackgroundColor="Default">
        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="PanGestureRecognizer_OnPanUpdated"/>
        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <Grid Margin="10">
            <Label Text="MAIN"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The `GridMain` can then be "panned away" to "show" the two labels.
But now I have the problem that the grids background color `Default` is not the target systems default background color, but `Transparent` -> I can "see" the labels underneath the grid. Also I can only pan the grid when I click/touch the string inside the grid and not anywhere inside the grid.

How can I set the background to use the "non-transparent" default background?
I do not want to use hard-coded `White` as I also want to support e.g. the dark theme for UWP and there it should be `Black`.

For now I used `Accent` to continue working, but that is not what I actually want.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza What do you mean with "implicit style"? Actually I'm fine with every solution that works ;-). Maybe also there is another content container besides a `Grid` that solves my problem?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Ah, ok. I don't think thats helping me, as this would still "hard-code" the color somehow - I would like to use/get the "system default"...

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza I don't want to set anything - I want to get the default system background, like `White` for iOS or `Black` for UWP using the dark theme...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you could create a dependency service that would return the color you want to use for the given OS.

First create a `IColorService` interface in the shared project:

```cs
public interface IColorService
{
    Color SystemBackgroundColor { get; }
}
```

Then implement it on each platform:

```cs
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(ColorService))]
namespace App.UWP
{
    public class ColorService : IColorService
    {
        public Color SystemBackgroundColor => 
            Application.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Dark ?
                Color.Black : Color.White;
    }
}
```

Next, create a static class in the shared project, that will allow easy access to the color:

```cs
public static class Colors
{
    public static Color SystemBackgroundColor => 
       DependencyService.Get<IColorService>().SystemBackgroundColor;
}
```

Finally use the color as the `BackgroundColor` of your `Grid`:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App"
             x:Class="App.MainPage">

    <Grid BackgroundColor="{x:Static local:Colors.SystemBackgroundColor}" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Notice the added `xmlns:local` pointing to the namespace where the `Colors` class is defined.

Comment: Thanks, works great. For Android/iOS I simply did `public Color SystemBackgroundColor => Color.White;`. Or is there a better way? (iOS only has "light" theme AFAIK, but Android I'm not sure)

Comment: Android has some theming capabilities but I am also not sure how they work. Maybe some Android developer could help :-). AFAIK however they are not "built-in" the system like on Windows.